# Math Looping Between Min and Max Using Mod?

Tags: math, module, range

i'm attempting to build a tiny (or perhaps not so tiny) formula that will contain numbers between a set min and max, but also loop these numbers so they are not clipped if they are outside of the range.  so far, this is what i have.

```
min1 = 10
max1 = 90

val1 = 92
//will make 11, which is what i want since it loops

formula:  min(max(min1,min(val1,max1)),mod(val1,max1)+min1)
```

however, i'd like it to loop the other direction also, so that if val1 is 5, which is -5 outside of min1, it will become 86.

another problem i'm running into is that

```
max1 % max1 != max1
```

as i want it to, since the max is part of the range

trying to be clear, here are some examples of desired output based on a range with looping

```
min1 = 10
max1 = 90
----------------------------------------------
val1 = 30    //within range: stays as 30 
val1 = 90    //within range: stays as 90
val1 = -6    //below range: loops to becomes 75
val1 = 98    //above range: loops to becomes 17
val1 = 91    //above range: loops to becomes 10
```

i'd like not to resort to using a series of if/else statements, but one would be fine if it's absolutely required.  is that even possible?

Comment: I think your last example should be 17, not 18 since you should count 10 too. Isn't it? You really want 91 to be 11 and not 10 whereas 90 is 90?

Comment: Does 90 stays 90 and 91 become 11 in your example? Is there nothing that becomes 10 then? What should happen with 170? Does it become 90 or 10? This is rather strange "looping".
Also, how could -6 become 84? -6 is 16 numbers far from minimum, so it should be around 90-16=74, or what?

Comment: oh.. ha... yeah, i totally wrote that wrong.  -6 should be 74, not 84.  sorry.

Comment: RE:  Mehrdad Afshari.  honestly, i have no idea what i was thinking when i wrote this.  you're absolutely right.  91 should be 10 to make a proper loop.  9 should be 90, 8 is 89.  i'm really sorry guys, i've been sending you on the bad direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int loop(int val, int min, int max)
{
    int p = max-min+1;
    int mod = (val-min)%p;
    if(mod<0)
        mod += p;
    return min+mod;
}
```

Comment: Why not just start out with `if (val == max) return max;`?

Comment: i'm terribly sorry.  i've been misleading you since i had my looping logic screwed up.  you noticed earlier but i didn't quite understand until now.  91 should be 10, not 11.  9 should become 90, etc. to make the loop correct.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, you should be able to do something like this:

```
((val-min) `mod` (max-min+1)) + min
```

Move your range down to be zero-based, clip off the high end, and shift it back to the right range.  Unfortunately, the % operator in C gives negative results for negative numbers.  So:

```
3 % 10 => 3
13 % 10 => 3
-3 % 10 => -3
-13 % 10 => -3
```

So to get rid of these negatives, we need one extra modulo:

```
((val-min)%(max-min+1) + (max-min+1)) % (max-min+1) + min
```

Comment: This is exactly the thing me and Pavel are doing, but your solution does not check for val<min scenario.

Comment: Re Rotsor: that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. Deleted previous answer. Try this one:

((val-min)%(max-min)+max-min)%(max-min)+min

EDIT: if you want max to be a valid value instead of overflowing to min, replace max by max+1 in all 3 places.

Comment: Who uses two divisions instead of one? :)
Also, 90 will become 10.

Comment: sorry pavel, i've edited my question because i had my looping logic confused.

Comment: @rotsor: 

  int Modulo(int x, int y)
  {
   int answer = x % y;

   return answer < 0 ? answer + std::abs(y) : answer;
  }